# What is the constant for "Previous Window" in Spy++?

Tags: windows, handle, spy++

In Spy++, can you click a Window in the list, then right-click it, select "Properties", and you will be shown a tab window in which you can select the tab "Windows".

In this window you can see the options "Next Window", "Previous Window", "Parent Window", etc..

If you click "Previous Window", it will show the previous window, but I am not sure in which way Spy++ determines what the "previous window" actually is.

I think Spy++ might looked up the previous window by using a constant like GW_PREVIOUS, but there is no such constant.

How or what does Spy++ do in such a case? Or does it only use the z-order of the windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using the constant `GW_HWNDPREV`. Not sure how you missed it since it's right there with all the other `GW_` values.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I really did not have it. It seems I copied them once from a website, was happy with it and never noticed that one constant was missing.

Comment: It's always a good idea to back and check the documentation for the function you're calling rather than just copying information second-hand from some random Web site.